# Help with limit calculation

Tags: limits

Can anyone help me with this limit please:

I have been trying to solve this for 2 hours with no success:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac {1^3+4^3+7^3+...+(3n-2)^3}{[1+4+7+...+(3n-2)]^2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the fraction using

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2},\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6},\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2.$$

The numerator is 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(3k-2)^3=\cdots=\frac 14 (27 n^4-18 n^3-9 n^2+4n).$$
The dinominator is 
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(3k-2)\right)^2=\cdots=\frac 14 n^2 (3 n-1)^2=\frac 14(9n^4-6n^3+n^2).$$

Hence, your limit will be
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{27 n^4-18 n^3-9 n^2+4n}{9n^4-6n^3+n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{27-18(1/n)-9(1/n^2)+4(1/n^3)}{9-6(1/n)+(1/n^2)}=3.$$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understood completely how did you computed the numerator would be great if you could explain to me :)

Comment: You are welcome! my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

We don't need to make all the detailed calculations as the highest exponent dominates when $n\to\infty$

$$1+4+7+...+(3n-2)=\frac n2\left(1+3n-2\right)=\frac{3n^2-n}2$$

$$\implies \left(1+4+7+...+(3n-2)\right)^2=\left(\frac{3n^2-n}2\right)^2=\frac{9n^4}4+O(n^3)$$

$$1^3+4^3+7^3+...+(3n-2)^3=\sum_{1\le r\le n}(3r-2)^3=\sum_{1\le r\le n}(27r^3-54r^2+36r-8)$$

$$=27\sum_{1\le r\le n}r^3-54\sum_{1\le r\le n}r^2+36\sum_{1\le r\le n}r-\sum_{1\le r\le n}8=27\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2+O(n^3)=\frac{27n^4}4+O(n^3)$$

So, the limit$(F)$ will be $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{9n^4}4+O(n^3)}{\frac{27n^4}4+O(n^3)}$$

Dividing the numerator & the denominator by $n^4,$

$$F=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{27}4+O\left(\frac1n\right)}{\frac94+O\left(\frac1n\right)}=\frac{\frac{27}4}{\frac94}$$

Comment: @Genadi, how about this?

Comment: Abit more complicated for me, but interesting! thanks

Comment: @Genadi, Observe that $$\sum_{1\le r\le n} r^k=\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}+O(n^k)$$ Its really not  amusing to know "more complicated":) We can safely focus on the highest powers only ignoring the rest sums

Comment: Good to know! by the way, can you tell me how to solve this:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(3k-2)^3$$
I have now clue how to get to the final solution:
$$\frac 14 (27 n^4-18 n^3-9 n^2+4n).$$
I probably dont get how to use the formula:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2.$$

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n(3k-2)^3=\sum_{k=1}^n(27k^3-54k^2+36k-8)=27\sum_{k=1}^n k^3-54\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+36\sum_{k=1}^nk-8\sum_{k=1}^n1$$ Then find this(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples) or the formula at the end of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12413/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-genadi)

Answer (score 0):

Approximate both sums by integrals (for example, the numerator by $\int_1^n (3x-2)^3 d x$), and you should be enlightened...